# EXEC Statement with parameters with single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute a stored procedure usp_find which accepts search string and shows the results.

It works fine normally for simple texts but when I try to execute with a parameter having single quotes, it is not able to execute:

```
EXECUTE usp_find 'code = ''A'''
```

My search string is `code = 'A'`, Here A is in single quotes so I applied two single quotes as we normally do for a quote to escape.

I am getting error :

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.
```

Any suggestions?

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_find(@LikeSearchstr VARCHAR(255))  
  AS  

  BEGIN  
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)  

    SET @cmd='  
    SELECT Name,OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) as Text_Definition  
    FROM sys.objects  
    WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE ''%'+@LikeSearchstr+'%'''  

   EXEC(@CMD)  
  END
```

Comment: Is sp_find a custom stored procedure? If yes, then [**do not use the `sp` prefix for custom SP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: can you add the code of sp_find as well?

Comment: I think the problem is inside that proc

Comment: Add the procedure definition can tell with the provided information why it isnt working.

Comment: You must be using it in dynamic SQL inside the proc.

Comment: Sp renamed to usp_find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for dynamic SQL here at all.

You can just use

```
SELECT Name,
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) AS Text_Definition
FROM   sys.objects
WHERE  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%' + @LikeSearchstr + '%'
```

Though I'd probably use `CHARINDEX` so it works correctly when you try and search for strings containing characters of special significance in the pattern syntax and `sys.sql_modules`.

```
SELECT object_name(object_id) AS Name,
       definition
FROM   sys.sql_modules
WHERE  CHARINDEX(@LikeSearchstr, definition) > 0
```

Comment: Also `sys.sql_modules` has been deprecated in SQL 2014 I think :)

Comment: @M.Ali - Are you thinking of `syscomments`? I don't see any deprecation notice https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx

Comment: syscommnets has definitely gone but you cannot see any documentation on  `sys.sql_modules` for 2014 either, maybe I am wrong, just wondering if it has also been deprecated.

Comment: @M.Ali - Yes you're wrong. 2014 is the current version . The above link is for 2014.

Comment: ops yes cheers thank you :)  `Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version), Azure SQL Database.`

Answer (score 4):

The clue here is "Line 4" in the error message.  I suspect the error is in the stored procedure rather than the calling code.  Post the code if you need help with fixing it.

More importantly, it seems the proc contains dynamic SQL and is not parameterized.  I suggest you follow the best practice of parameterizing it using sp_executesql.  Also, be aware the prefix 'sp_' is reserved for system stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using parameter concatenation

Try this...

```
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_find  --<-- sp_ prefix not a good practice
 @LikeSearchstr VARCHAR(255)  
  AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX)  --<-- nVarChar data type here

SET @cmd= N' SELECT Name,OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) as Text_Definition  
             FROM sys.objects  
             WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE ''%'' + @LikeSearchstr + ''%'' '  

 Exec sp_executesql @cmd
                   ,N'@LikeSearchstr VARCHAR(255) '
                   ,@LikeSearchstr  
END
```

Now when you execute this proc only pass the string you are looking for like...

```
Exec dbo.usp_find 'A'
```

Comment: Presumably they are in fact looking for the string `code = 'A'`

Comment: @MartinSmith True, also dynamic sql for this simple statement is really an overkill I think, it should be a simple query like you have mentioned in your answer :)

Answer (score -3):

```
set quoted_identifier off
declare @a  varchar(20) = "code = 'a'"
```